# PHP regular expression hours

Tags: php, regex, split

I have this regular expression in php:

```
$programacion_array = preg_split("/(([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}))/",$html, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

I want to split a text by finding the hours of the programs, sample text:

asdf**06:20**Programold**07:20**Programnew

But my regular expression is returning me this:

`[1] => 06:20 [2] => 06 [3] => 20 [4] => Programold`

I don't see what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting rid of the inner match groups, e.g. use just:

```
/([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})/
```

This will work as shown here: http://ideone.com/u44OIt